# How to understand this Promise code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

```
'use strict';

Promise.resolve(() => 'John')
  .then((args) => {
    console.log(args);
    throw new Error('ops')
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.log(ex)
  })
  .then(() => {
    throw new Error('ups')
    console.log('Doe')
  })
```

I think `console.log(args);` should output `'John'`, but when I run this code, the output is `[ [Function] ]`

So I am confused.

Comment: I think the output should be john, but instead it's `[Function]` - `console.log(() => 'john'))` - see what I did there?

Comment: `console.log(args());` will output *john*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` will create a new Promise resolved with the value you pass to it. So, in your case, your promise is actually resolved with the function object. It means that, the `then` handler is passed the function object itself.

What you should have done is

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('John'))
  .then(args => {
    console.log(args);
    throw new Error('ops')
  })
  .catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

Now, you are creating a `Promise` object and you are resolving that with the value `John`.

---

If you want your Promise to be resolved with a value readily, then don't pass the function object but pass the actual value itself to `Promise.resolve` function.

```
Promise.resolve('John')
  .then(args => {
    console.log(args);
    throw new Error('ops')
  })
  .catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

Now, you have a Promise, resolved with value `John` and the `then` handler will get the resolved value `John`.

**Note:** This is the recommended way of creating a Promise when you know the actual way to resolve with readily, so that you can avoid the [Promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1903116).

Comment: Alternatively: `Promise.resolve().then( () => "John" ).then( (args) => console.log(args) ...`

Comment: @aaaidan You cannot invoke the `Promise` constructor without passing a function object to it.

Comment: @thefourtheye `(args) => ` and `(ex) => `  can be reduced to `args => ` n `ex => `

Comment: It's worth noting that the result of a non-blocking function can be a function too and thus a function is a valid `Promise` value.

Answer (score 3):

```
'use strict';

Promise.resolve('John')
  .then((args) => {
    console.log(args);
    throw new Error('ops')
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.log(ex)
  })
  .then(() => {
    throw new Error('ups')
    console.log('Doe')
  })
```

I modify `Promise.resolve('John')`, it works.
Please see the [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

Answer (score 1):

resolve is used to pass the arguments directly to the then-handler

if you want 'John', you need to call the anonymous function in your call to resolve()

```
Promise.resolve(function(){return 'John';}());
```

notice the `}()` function call.

Comment: And how is this different from `Promise.resolve('John')`?

Comment: Of course it has no effect on the result passed to the "then"; however, I'm sure it's obvious that we have a useless function call getting in the way. Clearly my point was to illustrate what's going on when the OP sees [Function].